# Create video from images in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I try to develope the following in Flutter

1. The user can add multiple images to a gallery
2. The user can create a video from all these images with timelapse

The first step is no problem, but how to build the second step? How can I create a video from images in Flutter?

I found the `flutter_ffmpeg` plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg
Would this be possible with this package?

Otherwise this package above is very large. Are there other possibility to create a video from images with Flutter?

Comment: Were you ever able to get this functionality?

Comment: Can u share, how u added this functionality?

Comment: Could you share an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and I would recommend this package in the long run, because your expectations about how the video is created, may become more elaborated.

The package is large because it provides the full power of `ffmpeg` on all supported platforms. When you build an app for specific device (e.g., iPhone), the size penalty will hopefully be tolerable.

This said, you can build your own version of `flutter_ffmpeg` package removing all the external libraries that you don't need. Don't expect such cleanup to be easy, it may take few iterations before you settle on the right balance of size vs power.

Comment: any idea why this plugin is no longer connected ?

Comment: It was superseded by [FFmpegKit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit). See [FlutterFFmpeg to FFmpegKit Migration Guide](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Migrating-From-FlutterFFmpeg).

Comment: It looks like you have a background on this plugin , one question more and i will appreciate your answer .. i have read that this package support overlay image on video too . do you think it support if it also gives feature for position the image where image will be overlay?  i mean like topLeft or button ...etc ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan these features are part of FFmpeg, and nobody did something special to prevent them from working in Flutter. But on the other hand, you should be prepared to find that some less common features may have some glitches.

Answer (score 0):

With https://pub.dev/packages/image you can make animated GIF image, may be it will enough for you